# ImportRange and Query Function Data is condensing into one cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that imports data from one spreadsheet into another and then sorts that data by a key phrase. Here is the formula I am using:

```
=Query(Importrange("URL","ReferenceTab!Cell:Cell"), "Select * where Col2 = 'Lost'")
```

The problem that I am having is that this formula works on some of the tabs in the same spreadsheet, but then in others it causes all of the data to compile into one cell. I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter how many headers you have in your data, if it is only one then you need to set it to 1, by leaving it blank you are asking it to dynamically guess what the headers are.

> QUERY(data, query, [headers])

An additional issue is if you have columns consisting of mostly numbers it will erase all text so you need to decide if your data is supposed to be mostly text or mostly numbers as Query doesn't know how to handle both in the same column.